# pyspark logical conjunction for vertica sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, vertica

spark1.6,retrieve data from my Vertica database to work on it the below query is working well on vertica db but but its doesn't work on pyspark , Spark DataFrames support predicate push-down with JDBC sources but term predicate is used in a strict SQL meaning. It means it covers only WHERE clause. Moreover it looks like it is limited to the logical conjunction (no IN and OR I am afraid) and simple predicates, it shows this error  : **java.lang.RuntimeException: Option 'dbtable' not specified**

```
conf = (SparkConf()
.setAppName("hivereader")
.setMaster("yarn-client")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
.set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
.set("spark.executor.cores" , 7)
.set("spark.sql.inMemoryStorage.compressed", "true")
.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" , 2000)
.set("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled" , 'true')
.set("spark.port.maxRetries" , 200))

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

url = "*******"
properties = {"user": "*****", "password": "*******", "driver": "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver" }

df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    query = "SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' AND '2019-01-29'",
    **properties
).load()

df.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that—even though you say this query works on Vertica—your query is not written in a SQL syntax that Vertica will recognize. Your query should be rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION
FROM traffic.stats
WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' AND '2019-01-29'
```

Fixing all these errors, your `sqlContext.read` method should look like the following.

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    query = "SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' AND '2019-01-29'",
    **properties
).load()

df.show()
```

Or you can alias the table as a sub-query and use `dbtable` instead of `query`.

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    dbtable = "(SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' AND '2019-01-29') temp",
    **properties
).load()

df.show()
```

Comment: thank you , what about the below error after execution ": java.lang.RuntimeException: Option 'dbtable' not specified"

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh What version of Spark and Python are you running? My test was on Spark 2.4.0 and Python 2.7.10.

Comment: That error is a little confusing. `query` and `dbtable` are mutually exclusive, if you are using `query` in `options`, it should not be complaining that `dbtable` is missing. Can you post the exact code you used that created this error?

Comment: i have tried the `query = "SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-27' AND '2019-01-29' limit 10000000"
df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    dbtable="( " + query + " ) as temp",
    **properties
).load()

df.show()`

Comment: its worked with me but too slow in excution in long term

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh Please see my original response. You cannot specify a query with `dbtable`. You need to use `query` where you have `dbtable`. `...options(url = url, query="SELECT ... LIMIT 10000000", **properties).load()`.

Comment: pyspark 1.6 , python 3.4 and in the document they are saying : The JDBC table that should be read. Note that anything that is valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example, instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses.

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh You are right. My mistake. I was confused by syntax of using parentheses to form a subquery. Thank you for the clarification.